# Section height 100% not working

Tags: html, css, height

So I'm trying to make "sections" with `section` that covers up the full height of the current page. Kind of like [this](http://www.brandonjacoby.com/). As you can see the width is set to 100. And heres my code

```
.cont{
background: #009dff;
height: 100%;
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't seem to work. Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/vijaxuyu/1/edit). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

http://jsbin.com/vijaxuyu/2/edit?html,css,output

```
html{
  height:100%;
}
body{
  height:100%;
}
section {
  height: 100%;
}
```

The height % of `html` and `body` isn't by default 100%. Hence, you need to inform your browser explicitly. The reason why you have to specify `height` and sometimes `min-height` to `html` and `body` respectively is because neither element has any intrinsic `height`. Both are `height: auto` by default. It is the viewport that has 100% height, so `height: 100%` is taken from the viewport, then applied to `body` as a minimum to allow for scrolling of content.

Comment: Please add an explanation of why this is necessary.

Comment: Yes an explanation would be nice.

Comment: Just to note that, if you just want a blue background, you could add this to the body.

Comment: Just added the explanation.